# Trigger repainting a wicket component via push message

Tags: websocket, wicket

I understand the concept of repainting wicket components using `add(Component)` method of `AjaxRequestTarget` - but I can only use this method when the client triggers some ajax event.

But I have to repaint a component without any user interaction involved, so I can't use that. Next step was to discover `WebSocketBehavior` and it's associated method `onMessage()` - this message again gets a parameter of type `WebSocketRequestHandler` (which extends `AjaxRequestTarget`) to that I could add my to-be-repainted-component. But again this method seems only to be called when the client sends a websocket-message to the server.

Lastly I discovered I can trigger asynchronous messages from server side by opening an `IWebSocketConnection`. Wicketinaction suggests in this blog post (http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-native-websockets/) the following code lines:

```
IWebSocketConnectionRegistry registry = new SimpleWebSocketConnectionRegistry();
Application application = Application.get(wsApplicationName);
IWebSocketConnection wsConnection = registry.getConnection(application, wsSessionId, wsPageId);

if (wsConnection != null && wsConnection.isOpen()) {
  try {
    wsConnection.sendMessage("test");
  } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

wsApplication, wsSessionId and wsPageId are obtained in the `onConnect` method of the WebSocketBehavior.

In general this approach works - I can send my test message to the client and it receives exactly this text. But I can't find a way how to trigger a component repaint with this method. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated - or am I completely wrong in the end?

Comment: We use AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior, but that is not a push... Maybe [this](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Push) project on github can help you? I'd be interested to see what you find.

Comment: Looks interesting, but the last commit to that project was one year ago - I can't tell if thats the case because the project is so awesomely well designed that no bugfixes are needed or because the project is dead. As I'm working on a software with a pretty long life cycle I fear using this is not an option. I currently go with sending a push text message to the client who then sends a message back to trigger the onMessage method mentioned above. Other suggestions are still welcome. I will post this method as an answer later on, if no other ideas come up.

Comment: The answer is in the blog post you are linking to. When the client loads the page, set it to subscripe for update from your socket with Wicket.Event.subscribe. Then you can update your component via javascript or call an AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior to trigger a callback that updates your component.

Comment: Thats a similar solution to the one described in my previous comment. Unless it is not possible to push a component update directly from wicket (like with the sendMessage method, but not only with a string parameter) I have to stick with something like that - I just wanted to know if there is any standard-wicket-solution I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/tree/master/wicket6-websocket-broadcast.
This example shows exactly what you want.

https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/blob/master/wicket6-websocket-broadcast/src/main/java/com/wicketinaction/TimestamperTask.java#L27

https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/blob/master/wicket6-websocket-broadcast/src/main/java/com/wicketinaction/FeedPage.java#L78

Comment: This is even closer to my original question and offers a solution with less configuration effort and no need to add additional libraries. I guess, the `onEvent`-method of `FeedPage` is notified as soon as there is a broadcast from anywhere inside the program? Or do I have to link to the handler somehow?

Comment: No need to do anything manually. You have to use IWebSocketPushMessage message, note *Push*. https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/blob/master/wicket6-websocket-broadcast/src/main/java/com/wicketinaction/FeedItem.java#L9

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [https://github.com/papegaaij/wicket-atmosphere-quickstart/](https://github.com/papegaaij/wicket-atmosphere-quickstart/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/HomePage.java#L74) which is an example of pushing the current time repeatedly as a Wicket `Component` via Atmosphere (library to use WebSockets or fallbacks).

It is based on [wicket-atmosphere](https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-experimental/wicket-atmosphere) which in turn makes Atmosphere available in Wicket. The module is considered experimental hence the location in Wicket's repository. Despite this, it seems to work pretty reliably and is definitely worth a try.

The following fragments are taken from the mentioned example but make sure to read Atmosphere's documentation and the code of wicket-atmosphere to learn its API. Basically, you create a central event dispatcher and mark method of your pages with annotations that format the events as needed and send via the provided `AjaxRequestTarget`.

Creating an event to a central event dispatcher from a background job: `eventBus.post(new Date());`

Converting the event and sending as `Component`:

```
@Subscribe
public void updateTime(AjaxRequestTarget target, Date event) {
    timeLabel.setDefaultModelObject(event.toString());
    target.add(timeLabel);
}
```

Comment: This is a way cleaner solution and enables component updates via direct push message, no communication overhead needed. Thanks!